# Can I download my own binaries from iTunes Connect?

Tags: app-store-connect

The mac where I wrote my app is broken and so I cant access the code any more.

I uploaded it to my iTunes Connect account already. Is there a way to download the binaries from my account again?

Answer (score 8):

**Edit**

iTunes for Mac  version 12.7 removes the option to sync apps between your iOS devices and your Mac, and Apple has further removed the option to download iOS apps altogether from iTunes for Mac.

Consequently, the answer below no longer works... Bummer.

**Outdated answer**

As far as I know, there isn't a way to download the `ipa` (which is what's submitted to Apple) via `iTunesConnect`. However, it is possible to download the `.ipa` using `iTunes`.

Note, however, that the `ipa` will include resources (images, sound assets, etc), but the source code (`.h`, `.m.`, etc) will be in a compiled format. Unfortunately, AFAIK, there is no way to download the source code in a non-compiled format via either `iTunes` or `iTunesConnect`.

Still, the assets alone may be useful in recreating a project. To download the `ipa`, try this:

1. Find and download your app using iTunes on your Mac. This will download the `.ipa` that you uploaded.
2. Open Finder > Goto Music > iTunes > iTunes Media > Mobile Applications (under Mac OSX 10.8.2, possibly within another directory under different versions of OSX)
3. Copy and paste your `.ipa` to another location, such as the Desktop (so it doesn't confuse iTunes)
4. Unzip the `.ipa` (Right click on the `.ipa` > Open With > Archive Utility/The Unarchiver/similar unzip program)
5. In the unzipped directory, you'll find your app under "Payload" > Your_App_Name.app
6. Right click on your `.app` file > Show Package Contents

Comment: How was this ever voted up? The OPP asked how to download a ipa from itunes connect and you never touched any of that.

Comment: @jahrichie, it was up voted because someone found it useful, so I'm leaving it here. However, I've edited my answer to reflect that, AFAIK, you can't download the `ipa` file via `iTunesConnect` (as of the current date). If you know a way to do such, please submit your own answer. Otherwise, it *is possible* to download the `ipa` via `iTunes`. Still, this is only useful if you're interested in only the assets (also reflected in revised answer).

Comment: I can confirm this works though the Archive Utility did not work on OSX 10.8.5.  I had to use the Stuffit Expander on the .ipa file to get an archive with the Payload Folder.

Comment: Is it possible to upload it again an another account then?